# VisualStudio Code not getting option "Deploy Source to Org"

Tags: lightning-web-components, trailhead, visualstudiocode

I am starting to learn LWC and trying to create the HelloWorld example as described in in trailhead. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the trailhead but I don't get the option SFDX:Deploy Source to Org. Please let me know what I could be missing

[image]

Comment: I suggest you close your folder, log out from all the authorized Orgs. Relaunch the VS Code. VS code has an update which might be a possible reason. Once you relaunch it, Open your folder, authorize the org and I hope option should come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys after no luck with what was suggested by @sanket kumar, I could overcome this problem and this is what was the problem. I had installed Salesforce CLI from the link given in trailhead for Windows 64 bit https://sfdc.co/sfdx_cli_win64 . I closed VS Code, uninstalled Salesforce CLI and this time installed CLI from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli. And now when I open VS Code it works like a charm now. I shall try to figure out a way to report this to Traihead team.